Picking specific fields for an active model serializer association
In Active Model Serializers.. Let's say I have CompanySerializer and EmployeeSerializer.  On CompanySerializer I have a field ceo where I want to render the association with EmployeeSerializer but only show a subset of the fields from EmployeeSerializer.
For the purposes of this example, let's say that EmployeeSerializer has the attributes name, homepage, and salary, but on CompanySerializer.ceo we only want to show name and homepage.
I would like to avoid redefining a new CompanyEmployeeSerializer class, if I can just "pick" the fields that I want for the employee association inside CompanySerializer.
I also want to avoid a solution that runs EmployeeSerializer then slices for specific fields.  The reason for this is I want to avoid running the code associated with serializing the non-desired fields.
Note: this is different than the question of how you hide certain fields inside a serializer based on a condition.  This is about how you can call a serializer from another serializer and get specific fields.
If something like this existed, I'd be quite happy:
CompanySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  belongs_to :ceo, serializer: EmployeeSerializer, fields: [:name, :homepage]
end


https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/general/fields.md

@max I saw that, but it's at the controller level, not the serializer level.  I want the association in the serializer to pick the right fields for serialization.

I added the Note @engineersmnky but I want to note that you should have never marked this for closing, obviously it's different than the question of conditional fields and this is superfluous.

@BenG as I understand it you want to conditionally display salary for the specific employee that is in the ceo field. Is there nothing in that object that qualifies it as ceo when being serialized?

@engineersmnky There would be two endpoints, companies/ and employees/.  So the condition is whether you're querying it as an association on companies vs just querying employees by itself.  Condition is not the ideal way to think about it in the first place, because you're dealing with different serializers in each case.  If I add a third endpoint, I'd be able to want to specify the specific fields I want from employee association there too.

I provided an example of what would solve it if it existed

This is as close as I could get:
# app/serializers/company_serializer.rb

class CompanySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  belongs_to :ceo do
    EmployeeSerializer.new(object.ceo).attributes([:name, :homepage])
  end
end


Could you do it this way?
# app/serializers/company_serializer.rb

class CompanySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  belongs_to :ceo, serializer: EmployeeSerializer, fields: [:name]
end

You'd have to dig deep:
$ git diff
  diff --git a/lib/active_model/serializer.rb b/lib/active_model/serializer.rb
  index 5e34779..e50f44f 100644
  --- a/lib/active_model/serializer.rb
  +++ b/lib/active_model/serializer.rb
  @@ -367,7 +367,9 @@ module ActiveModel
         adapter_options ||= {}
         options[:include_directive] ||= ActiveModel::Serializer.include_directive_from_options(adapter_options)
         if (fieldset = adapter_options[:fieldset])
  -        options[:fields] = fieldset.fields_for(json_key)
  +        if fields = fieldset.fields_for(json_key)
  +          options[:fields] = fields
  +        end
         end
         resource = attributes_hash(adapter_options, options, adapter_instance)
         relationships = associations_hash(adapter_options, options, adapter_instance)
  diff --git a/lib/active_model/serializer/association.rb b/lib/active_model/serializer/association.rb
  index 7aeee33..ce0cd29 100644
  --- a/lib/active_model/serializer/association.rb
  +++ b/lib/active_model/serializer/association.rb
  @@ -55,7 +55,8 @@ module ActiveModel
           association_object = association_serializer && association_serializer.object
           return unless association_object

  -        serialization = association_serializer.serializable_hash(adapter_options, {}, adapter_instance)
  +        options = {fields: reflection.options[:fields]}.compact
  +        serialization = association_serializer.serializable_hash(adapter_options, options, adapter_instance)

           if polymorphic? && serialization
             polymorphic_type = association_object.class.name.underscore

Monkey patch to give it a try:
# config/initializers/serializer_patch.rb

ActiveModel::Serializer::Association.class_eval do
  def serializable_hash(adapter_options, adapter_instance)
    association_serializer = lazy_association.serializer
    return virtual_value if virtual_value
    association_object = association_serializer && association_serializer.object
    return unless association_object

    # pass `fields:` option from the reflection to serializer
    options = {fields: reflection.options[:fields]}.compact
    serialization = association_serializer.serializable_hash(adapter_options, options, adapter_instance)

    if polymorphic? && serialization
      polymorphic_type = association_object.class.name.underscore
      serialization = {type: polymorphic_type, polymorphic_type.to_sym => serialization}
    end
    serialization
  end
end

ActiveModel::Serializer.class_eval do
  def serializable_hash(adapter_options = nil, options = {}, adapter_instance = self.class.serialization_adapter_instance)
    adapter_options ||= {}
    options[:include_directive] ||= ActiveModel::Serializer.include_directive_from_options(adapter_options)
    if (fieldset = adapter_options[:fieldset])

      # fix controller `fields:` always overriding our patched fields option 
      # even if you don't pass `fields:` to `render`:
      if fields = fieldset.fields_for(json_key)
        options[:fields] = fields
      end

    end
    resource = attributes_hash(adapter_options, options, adapter_instance)
    relationships = associations_hash(adapter_options, options, adapter_instance)
    resource.merge(relationships)
  end
end

Test:
>> CompaniesController.renderer.render(json: Company.first)
=> "{\"id\":1,\"name\":null,\"ceo\":{\"name\":null}}"


I like this attributes approach you took, and am going to try it out.  Is it correct to say that the undesired fields won't have serialization code run on them?

@BenG yes, looks like only the requested attributes are fetched, it's definitely not slice: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.14/lib/active_model/serializer.rb#L336

This worked quite well.  Marking as correct. However I wish they just had an :attributes key instead of requiring a block.

One addendum to make here: you should check object.ceo isn't nil inside the belongs_to association, if that's a possibility. Otherwise you'll get an error from trying to serialize nil
